# Iterative Methods applied to singular Matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

For singular A, split A = M - N with non-singular N. Prove that stationary iterative method will not converge to x* for any splitting of A.

I am attempting to construct a proof for this question from my homework assignment, I have an idea where to start but not sure exactly what to do with it. The result is obvious since we wouldn't expect there to be a solution x* for a singular matrix, and I want to prove this by showing that $p(M^{-1}N) > 1$ for all M, N, which would be sufficient.

For singular A, given M is non-singular, I am thinking if there is anything we know about N that would require the result above to hold. No information is given explicitly about N but I think I need to infer something for this proof.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

for singular $A$, $Av = \lambda v$ gives $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue. So we have:
$$ Av = 0 $$ 
$$ (M-N)v = 0 $$ 
$$ Mv = Nv $$
$$ v = M^{-1}Nv $$
$$ 1v = M^{-1}Nv $$
so $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $M^{-1}N$

therefore $\rho(M^{-1}N) \ge 1$